# error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'double' from type 'double *'

Tags: array, c, punteros

Tengo una variable compra definda como un puntero y asignada una dirección en memoria llamada clientes

```
double *compra = (double*)malloc(clientes * sizeof(char*));
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es pedirle a usuario que ingrese el contendo de la variable compra y lo hago de esta manera (errónea)

```
compra[i] = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
```

pero tira error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'double' from type 'double *'

¿como sería la forma correcta de leer este tipo de puntero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > incompatible types when assigning to type 'double' from type 'double *'

Este error de compilación significa que estás asignando el *valor* de una variable de tipo `double*` en un variable de tipo `double`. Por ejemplo:

```c
double* pa = NULL;
double a = pa; // Error de compilación porque "pa" no es de tipo "double".
```

En tu ejemplo sucede exactamente lo mismo:

```c
compra[i] = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
```

`compra[i]` es de tipo `double` y luego conviertes el puntero devuelto por *malloc* a `double*`, los tipos siguen siendo incompatibles.

Como verás, esta instrucción:

```c
(double*)malloc(clientes * sizeof(char*));
```

Reserva memoria para un **array de punteros a `char`**, así que para acceder a ese *array de punteros* necesitas de un **puntero doble**, por lo que el tipo de la variable `compra` debe ser de tipo `double**`:

```c
double** compra = (double**)malloc(clientes * sizeof(char*));
```

Ahora la semántica de esta instrucción cambia:

```c
compra[i] = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
```

Porque ahora `compra[i]` es de tipo `double*` y *malloc* devuelve un puntero a `void*` que luego es convertido a `double*`, por lo que los tipos son compatibles.

### Observación

En C no necesitas convertir los tipos `void*` a otro tipo, esa conversión la hace el compilador de manera implícita:

```c
double **compra = malloc(clientes * sizeof(char*));
compra[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Me anduvo, pero cuando en esta intrucción tira error   double total=compra[i]*0.80; porque lo estoy tratando como una variable pero es un puntero

Comment: @AlejandroCaro `compra[i]` es de tipo `double*`, no lo puedes tratar como un `double`. Podrías acceder al dato de la compra así: `compra[i][j]`. Lo que has creado literalmente es un *array bidimensional*, solo que de forma dinámica.